# mod_rewrite rule to append index.html if not present

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

What would be the mod_rewrite rule to append `index.html` to any URL that ends with a forward slash? The rule should preserve any query string present. I can't use the `DirectoryIndex` directive because the `index.html` files don't physically exist on the file system, but are required by the underlying website framework.

Some example URLs and the desired results are shown below:

```
http://example.com/                   -> http://example.com/index.html
http://example.com/?a=1               -> http://example.com/index.html?a=1
http://example.com/foo/               -> http://example.com/foo/index.html
http://example.com/foo/?b=2           -> http://example.com/foo/index.html?b=2
http://example.com/foo/index.html     -> http://example.com/foo/index.html
http://example.com/foo/index.html?c=3 -> http://example.com/foo/index.html?c=3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Query strings automatically get appended by mod_rewrite unless the query string itself is being modified. This should be what you need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/$ /$1/index.html [L,R=301]
```

This makes it so when someone requests anything that ends with a `/`, redirect the browser to the same URL with `index.html` at the end. A blank URI was a special case (first rule). If you don't need to redirect the browser, just remove the `,R=301` from the square brackets.

Comment: I think you can help this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407592/configure-htaccess-file-with-two-sites-to-serve